How do I categorize projects in a dataframe according to its title?
I have a dataframe where I want to categorize energy releated projects in 4 different topics according to its title.
For that I want to use pre-defined keywords to identify which topic the project relates to and categorize them accordingly.
The topics and key-words are:

energy efficiency : efficiency AND (procedure* OR process* OR equipment* OR system* OR motor*)

fossil fuels: oil OR (natural AND gas) OR LNG OR carbon

renewable energy: (solar AND energy) OR (wind AND energy) OR (renewable AND energy) OR biofuel* OR biomass*

nuclear energy:  nuclear AND power AND plant


Using the keywords I want to create a new column to inform the topic of the project. The project can be classified in more than one topic.
I have df['title'] and I want to create df['topic'] with values based on my pre-defined keywords.
EXAMPLE

Project 1:

INPUT 
df['title'] = 'Integral Use of Biomass in Electric Power Generation and Use of Heat to Increase Energy Efficiency'
OUTPUT 
df['topic']= [1,3]


Project 2:

INPUT 
df['title'] = 'simulation of power plant based on nuclear fusion'
OUTPUT 
df['topic'] = [4]


Project 3:
INPUT 
df['title'] =  'new industrial processes in the oil sector to increase energy efficiency'
OUTPUT
df['topic']=[1,2]

I think regex would be a nice way to identify the keywords in the title of each project.
I tried using isin but I don´t know how to set regex expression neither how to use them together.
I am also open to new solutions to classify projects other than that!

I can think of two options, both using regex patterns. The first one uses re with a listcomp, and is easier to understand, imo. The second uses pandas.DataFrame.str.contains.
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {
    "title": [
        "Integral Use of Biomass in Electric Power Generation and Use of Heat to Increase Energy Efficiency",
        "simulation of power plant based on nuclear fusion",
        "new industrial processes in the oil sector to increase energy efficiency",
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

patterns = {
    1: r"(?=.*efficiency)(?=.*(procedure|process|equipment|system|motor))",
    2: r"oil|natural.*gas|LNG|carbon",
    3: r"(?=.*solar.*energy)|(?=.*wind.*energy)|(?=.*renewable.*energy)|biofuel|biomass",
    4: r"(?=.*nuclear)(?=.*power)(?=.*plant)",
}

# Option 1
df["topic"] = df["title"].apply(
    lambda title: [
        topic
        for topic, pattern in patterns.items()
        if re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE).search(title)
    ]
)

# Option 2
df["topic"] = [[] for _ in range(len(df))]
for topic, pattern in patterns.items():
    mask = df["title"].str.contains(pattern, case=False, regex=True)
    df.loc[mask, "topic"] = df.loc[mask, "topic"].apply(lambda x: x + [topic])

Both will output:
                                               title   topic
0  Integral Use of Biomass in Electric Power Gene...     [3]
1  simulation of power plant based on nuclear fusion     [4]
2  new industrial processes in the oil sector to ...  [1, 2]


Nice! thank you. What the expression   ?=.*  means in this case?

@BarbaraBressanRocha ?= is a positive lookahead assertion. In this case it's looking for any string followed by the specific string in the parentheses. For instance, (?=.*nuclear)(?=.*power)(?=.*plant) will match strings that contain nuclear, power and plant in any order, along with any other characters.

Seems like mostly an implementation problem. We can create two helper functions, _and and _or which check if all instances input to _and and if any instances input to _or are respected.
import pandas as pd


def get_topic(title: str) -> str:
    """
    RULES:
    energy efficiency : efficiency AND (procedure* OR process* OR equipment* OR system* OR motor*)

    fossil fuels: oil OR (natural AND gas) OR LNG OR carbon

    renewable energy: (solar AND energy) OR (wind AND energy) OR (renewable AND energy) OR biofuel* OR biomass*

    nuclear energy: nuclear AND power AND plant
    """

    def _and(keywords: list[str]) -> bool:
        return all(keyword in title for keyword in keywords)

    def _or(keywords: list[str]) -> bool:
        return any(keyword in title for keyword in keywords)

    title = title.lower()
    suggestions = []

    if _and(["efficiency"]) and _or(
        ["procedure", "process", "equipment", "system", "motor"]
    ):
        suggestions.append(1)

    if _or(["oil", "lng", "carbon"]) or _and(["natural", "gas"]):
        suggestions.append(2)

    if (
        _and(["solar", "energy"])
        or _and(["wind", "energy"])
        or _and(["renewable", "energy"])
        or _and(["biofuel"])
        or _and(["biomass"])
    ):
        suggestions.append(3)

    if _and(["nuclear", "power", "plant"]):
        suggestions.append(4)

    return suggestions


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "title": [
            "Integral Use of Biomass in Electric Power Generation and Use of Heat to Increase Energy Efficiency",
            "simulation of power plant based on nuclear fusion",
            "new industrial processes in the oil sector to increase energy efficiency",
        ]
    }
)

df["topic"] = df["title"].apply(get_topic)

print(df)

Additionally, if you do not like passing in the arguments to _and and _or as a list, you can modify them to:
    def _and(*keywords) -> bool:
        return all(keyword in title for keyword in keywords)

    def _or(*keywords) -> bool:
        return any(keyword in title for keyword in keywords)

and then use _and as: _and("keyword1", "keyword1", ...).
